# Using \ensuremath inside \text

Tags: amsmath

Using `\ensuremath` inside `\text` works fine and gives good results. However, I realized that the spacing in superscripts changes. I tried working with `\mathchoice`, but that doesn't know that it is in a superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\somepackagecommand[1]{\text{#1}}
\newcommand*\mytextmathstatement{calculate \ensuremath{1-1}}
\sffamily
\noindent
\mytextmathstatement\\
$\somepackagecommand{\mytextmathstatement}$\\% ok - identical
\somepackagecommand{\mytextmathstatement}% ok - identical

\noindent
$2^{\text{calculate }1-1}$\\
$2^{\somepackagecommand{\mytextmathstatement}}$\\% spacing differs
\end{document}
```

It's a weird thing. I get the superscript font size, but the (scaled-down) normal spacings. Setting `\scriptstyle` by hand would shrink the font too much.

Any idea how to 'perfectly escape' from within `\text` to `\math`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't recommend this! Use `\text` for real non-math typesetting and `\ensuremath` for real math content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a mystery and `\ensuremath` has nothing to do with this. You of course get the same result from

```
$a^{\text{calculate \ensuremath{1-1}}}$
```

and

```
$a^{\text{calculate $1-1$}}$
```

Why this is different from `$a^{\text{calculate }1-1$`?

By general TeX rules, spaces around binary operation or relation symbols are not added if they appear in a superscript or in a subscript.

However, `\text` works in a different fashion: when you say `\text{<material>}` you're really typesetting four boxes:

```
\mbox{\everymath{\displaystyle}\fontsize\f@size{0}\selectfont <material>}
\mbox{\everymath{\textstyle}\fontsize\f@size{0}\selectfont <material>}
\mbox{\everymath{\textstyle}\fontsize\sf@size{0}\selectfont <material>}
\mbox{\everymath{\textstyle}\fontsize\ssf@size{0}\selectfont <material>}
```

and then TeX chooses the one that's relevant, in your case the third one. So math is typeset as if it were at the higher level, which means spaces *are* inserted around binary operation or relation symbols.

Implementing the removal of those spaces could only be done by setting `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` to zero, but this would mean you can't use them to add space where you want it.

Answer (score 3):

You get the tighter superscript spacing back with

```
$2^{\somepackagecommand{calculate \ensuremath{1{-}1}}}$
```

It's probably possible to make a variant of `\text` that does this automatically but better really to avoid `\text` and `\ensuremath`

I would normally use

```
$2^{\text{calculate }1-1}$
```

If you really need inter-word spacing and

```
$2^{\mathrm{something}-2}
```

if you don't.

---

In the updated MWE you could use

```
$2^{\medmuskip=0mu \somepackagecommand{\mytextmathstatement}}$
```

There's a chance someone has used `\medmuskip` explicitly and this would also affect that as well as automatic spacing around binary operators, but probably, they haven't.

Comment: Yes, this would work around this issue. I was interested in a real escaping solution. I therefore changed the MWE in my question.

Comment: @mh246 extended my answer for the new MWE